# How to compare difference of two fields with a constant in a query?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, cloudant

I am new to this and hope i will get some help here.
So what i want is to fetch only the details from my NOSQL db(Cloudant) where the fields `"end"` and `"start"` have difference greater than or equal to `(24*60*60*1000)`.

My Data looks something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "_xyz": "yyyyyyyyyy",
  "instance": [
    {
      "instance_id": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
      "usage": [
        {
          "start": 1559624400016,
          "end": 1559714400000,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

My query looks like this :-

```
{
"selector": {
           "$and": [
              {
                 "instances": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                       "usage": {
                          "$elemMatch": {
                             "end": {
                                "$gte": "start"-(24*60*60*1000)
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
}
```

This is wrong and i dunno what to do. i am stuck.

It would be nice if i could get some help as i am new to NOSQL db and if it possible please guide me to some good docs to learn more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution to your problem using the aggregate pipeline ensuring difference between end and start is 86400000ms, your problem can't be solved using simple mongo query as you have double nested array, usually try to keep it to 1 nested level as if it's greater that one nested level you have to use the aggregate pipeline for filtering

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$instance"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      _xyz: 1,
      instance: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$instance.usage",
              as: "item",
              cond: {
                $gte: [
                  {
                    $toLong: {
                      $subtract: [
                        "$$item.end",
                        "$$item.start",

                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  86400000
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "mapItem",
          in: {
            instance_id: "$instance.instance_id",
            usage: {
              start: {
                $toLong: "$$mapItem.start"
              },
              end: {
                $toLong: "$$mapItem.end"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        _xyz: "$_xyz"
      },
      instance: {
        $push: "$instance"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you have any doubt or issue do let me know.

Comment: I would suggest you to post your code as the answer instead of links to a mongo playground as your answer can be deleted on those grounds.